# -malways versus -mdefault on for EE 1.13

Tags: cron, enterprise-1.13

What is the correct cron setting for Magento 1.13 to ensure Cache does NOT invalidate itself.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php html/cron.php -mdefault
```

or

```
 * * * * * /usr/bin/php html/cron.php -malways
```

I am assuming the malways tag should be run for EE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither directly, you should execute `cron.sh` which in turn will execute both.

Running `cron.php` directly without a sanity check will cause overlapping of crons, duplicate processing and excessive resource consumption.

FPC invalidation of content is driven by the configuration defined in `Enterprise/PageCache`'s `config.xml`.